# How to create a Event in a normal class by swift?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I want to create an login template in a normal class,but in the class,the view can't call the event,no "sss" be printed when the Event triggered

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITextFieldDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let loginView=login(view: self.view,controller:self)
        loginView.setView();

    }
}
```

```
import UIKit
class login{
    let PassWord=UITextField()
    let view:UIView!
    let controller:ViewController
    init(view:UIView,controller:ViewController){
        self.view=view
        self.controller=controller
    }

    func setView(){
        initPassWord()
        print("1")

    }
    func initPassWord(){
        PassWord.placeholder="PassWord"
        PassWord.addTarget(self, action: #selector(login.exits(_:)), for:.allEvents)
        //PassWord.addTarget(controller, action: #selector(login.exits(_:)), for:.allEvents)
    }
    @IBAction func  exits(_ sender:UITextField){
        print("sss")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
var loginView:Login! // hold a strong reference here , start class names with capital letter 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      loginView = Login(controller:self)
      loginView.setView();
}
```

Also make it weak

```
weak var controller:ViewController
```

as not to cause retain cycles

BTW you only need to send the controller , and there you can access it's view